# Can a LABEL block be used without loop?

Tags: java, labeled-statements

Can a LABEL block be used without loop? Any examples?

Answer (score 16):

[Here](http://java.sun.com/developer/TechTips/2000/tt0613.html) is an example of using labels and break statements without a loop:

```
        block1: {
            if (a < 0) {
                break block1;
            }
            if (b < 0) {
                break block1;
            }
            return a + b;
        }
```

Comment: How about using LABEL wihout being in the defined LABEL. Like if(i ==0){
  continue label1;
} else {
//do something
}

label1: {
//do something
}

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It is actually a disguised goto, which isn't allowed in Java.

Answer (score 4):

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    hello: break hello;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

**But why use a label on a code block?**

My application is usually a switch on a String variable (or anything other than char, byte, short, int, Enum).

*"To make an omelette, you have to break some eggs"*

**Example:**

```
String key = "scrambled";
eggs: {
    if ("do-nothing".equals(key)) break eggs;
    if ("scrambled".equals(key)) {
        ;//scramble code here
        break eggs;
    }
    if ("fried".equals(key)) {
        ;//fry code here
        break eggs;
    }
    //default behaviour goes here
    //or maybe throw an exception
}
```

Ok, ok, *"Sometimes, to make an omelette, you have to kill a few people"*

**Alternatives:**

- Java 7 allows String as the switch.
- An Enum workaround using
  MyEnum.valueOf(str) can be made to work.
- A switch on the String (or
  Object)'s hashcode plus some more `if-then-else if` is possible but
  would only make sense for lots of possibilities, in which case the
  whole thing is probably due for an overhaul.

Answer (score 3):

certainly:

```
private boolean isSafe(String data) {

    validation: {

        if (data.contains("voldemort")) {
            break validation;
        }
        if (data.contains("avada")) {
            break validation;
        }
        if (data.contains("kedavra")) {
            break validation;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

@DragonBorn: that's not possible. You can only continue or break a label from within it's scope, for example:

```
    label1: for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + j);
            if (i == j) {
                continue label1;
            }
        }
    }
```

produces:

```
0 0
1 0
1 1
2 0
2 1
2 2
3 0
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

Comment: How about using LABEL wihout being in the defined LABEL. Like if(i ==0){
  continue label1;
} else {
//do something
}

label1: {
//do something
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want some unreadable code:

```
int i = 1;
int j = 1;
label: switch (i) {
case 1:
    switch (j) {
    case 1:
        break label;
    }
default:
    System.out.println("end");
}
```

Without `break;` will print "end". `break label;` will skip the print.