# What are the codes on which java labels can be applied other than loops?

Tags: java, loops, label

I just wanted to know all other codes on which java labels can be applied. I only know that labels can be applied on loops.

In Kathie Sierra It was written that:-

> Although many statements in a java program can be labeled, it's most common to use labels with loop statements...

From Link: [Can a label block be used without loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939924/can-a-label-block-be-used-without-loop)

I get reference that label can be applied on blocks or can be used with single statement like :
`hello: break hello;`

> Still question is can we apply label on any statement or block...

```
label1:int a=3;   //ERROR
label1:{int a=3; }  //legal
```

Why??

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question noted. The other question asks if there are *any* uses of `label` besides loops, whereas this question asks for *all* uses of `label`.

Comment: @RedRoboHood-Actually, those answers cover almost all the cases. I traversed each one of them to ensure this. SO, Oli Sir has done a good job.

Comment: @shekharsuman Needing to go through all the answers to find *almost* all of the use cases is not enough. It does not answer this question.